# Android: Download images from web and show them on gridview

Tags: android, image, download, android-asynctask

I want to create a program that gets some images from a webpage, and shows them on a gridview. I dont know how many of them exactly. It could be from 20 to 30. Ill do it with asynctask, which i have allready used before and more or less know how it works. But i don't know which way use it this time.

For now, what i would like to get is a progressbar (circle clicking) while image is downloading. And once its downloaded, it would disappear and image will load. I will use an array of objects with an adapter, to fill the gridview.

Which way would you use the asynctask?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you check out [Lecture 6](http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/src6-dan/Threads03/src/net/cs76/lectures/Threads03/) of Harvard Extension CS76. There is a `URLImageAdapter` and example source code that does example what you are looking for.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save downloaded images and reuse them in future then you must look [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

To display dialog with cycling circle, look this: [howto use ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

Comment: I dont really need to save them. Just show them. Every box of the gridview will have one, with some text. And the user can click on any on them, and another activity will open. For now, ive the adapter, and the object that fills the boxes, with its setters and getters.