# Bouncycastle AES 256 multithreading decryption speed degradation because of JIT

Tags: android, encryption, aes, jit, bouncycastle

I am writing application that encrypts photos and though it need decrypt and show thumbnails in gallery like activity. Then of course you can click and see full sized image in different activity.
I am using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding cipher with 256 bit key. I derive cipher key using PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC and store it into memory. Then all threads that need to make encryption/decryption is using that key from memory initializing Cipher object with it.

So here is my problem. When I decrypt many images simultaneously (let's say I need to show up gallery) and after I try to decrypt full sized image, it's extremely slow. On the other hand if I decrypt just one image (no matter what size), then go to gallery then decrypt full size image it is very fast.

I am really confused.

So what I am doing wrong? Maybe Bouncy Castle Crypto library is not thread safe?

**UPDATE:** I've found out this problem is related to JIT. Disabling JIT totally eliminates any processing speed difference. Can anyone help to understand how to optimize code to force  JIT compile right part of the code when decrypting photos with multithreading to gain same speed as if decrypting only one photo at the beginning?

Comment: There are different meanings of thread safe. How are you using Bouncy Castle?

Comment: User enter password and I derive 256 bit encryption key using PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC algorithm. Then I initialize decryption cipher using Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "bc"). The I am using standard CipherInputStream to decrypt files. Thats all.

Comment: In particular if you share any instances between threads.

Comment: No. I initialize my cipher with every thread using Cipher.getInstance(). The only shared thing is my key which is object of SecretKey.

Comment: I'm guessing each thread uses that key a LOT during decryption.  I'm not sure how the Android Dalvik VM works at a low level but if it's anything like the JVM or .NET, it may be that each thread is locking that shared key each time it needs to read it (which is probably all the time in this case).  Try passing a copy of the key to each worker thread, so that it doesn't have to share with the others.

Comment: Are you sure your threads trying to decrypt the small images are done when you attempt to decrypt the full sized image? Is it possible that they are still lingering, eating up CPU?

Comment: The thing is when all threads are finished (I checked with DDMS) I try to decrypt one single photo with one thread. The weird thing is if I decrypt many small photos then decrypt one last it's very slow, if I decrypt one then decrypt many then again decrypt one it's super fast.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed code to generate key every time with every new thread and everything is the same. So it's not connected with shared key.

Comment: I've found out that this issue is related with JIT. See Update.

Comment: I would be more concerned regarding the memory management, the garbage collector may be working over-time. Try increasing the heap space and see if/how that changes things, or try different garbage collection schemes. Images tend to take lots of memory.

Comment: Increasing heap size speeds up little bit(around 200ms), but the problem with big speed difference exists whether I am decrypting only one or multiple images.

Comment: The only scenario I can think of would be a bug in JIT module, causing  the same classes to be compiled over and over for each thread. How many threads are we talking about with your implementation?

Comment: About 20 threads simultaneously decrypting thumbnails (each about 15K size).

Comment: Can you easily change the number of threads that you use? I suspect that plotting the time versus number of threads, you'll see the you actually start losing performance after 4 or 5 threads (depending on number of cores on your phone). What I suspect is that the high number of CPU-bound threads are causing the JIT compiler thread to be starved, and the rest of the JIT infrastructure to simply waste time identifying same code traces to be compiled repeatedly.

Comment: Number of threads depend on how much GridView is calling getView() that makes decryption in separate thread and shows thumbnail. I think best solution will be to decrypt thumbnails in single thread one by one and place decrypted data into memory cache for GridView to use later. In this case I will not make any simultaneous decryptions. What you think? Maybe you can suggest better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our discussion above, a likely culprit in the performance degradation is the high number of worker threads. One possible method for limiting the number of threads is to use a fixed (or capped) thread pool, using the classes found in `java.util.concurrent`.

You could create a fixed thread pool execution service using a suitable `Executors` static factory method. Then, you can create asychronous tasks for decrypting individual thumbnails and populating the GridView cells using the returned `ExecutorService` instance's `submit()` method.

Another possibility may be the new [Loaders API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) (developer.android.com), but I am not sure. I am reading about them right now for my own use. So you may want to check the documentation.

Yet another alternative is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319593/391315) (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Well spotted vhallac, I did not expect such a large number of threads. I would certainly limit the number of threads to the number of processor cores (hyperthreaded or not) and use the concurrency utilities.